# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection when I try to open MAP on marshmellow version

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native, google-maps-markers

I try to load `map` to get customize `marker`, and the app running normal on `Android Version 9 (PIE)`. But when I try to build on `marshmellow version`, it doesn't work. I put debugger on `console.log` the error is:

> "
>   Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
>   Object {
>     "PERMISSION_DENIED": 1,
>     "POSITION_UNAVAILABLE": 2,
>     "TIMEOUT": 3,
>     "code": 3,
>     "message": "Location request timed out",
>   }
>   "

Maybe there are suggestions that can help?
Thanks before..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using [react-native-geolocation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation). It looks like this is a [known open issue](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation/issues/43) regarding GPS not working in some android systems.

The current workaround is to use `enableHighAccuracy: false`. Alternatively you may want to check out [react-native-geolocation-service](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service).

Hope this helps you.